# Why am i getting this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'load'

Tags: python, arrays, json

When ever I try to load data from a json file I get this error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'load'

What I expected

```
import json
users=[]
with open('username project.json','w') as f:
    jfile=json.dump(users,f)

def create_usernames():
    username=input('Enter in username')
    with open('username project.json','r+') as read:
        usersj=users.load(read)
    if username in users[usersj]:
            print('username rejected')
    else:
        print('username is okay')
create_usernames()
```

What resulted

```
usersj=users.load(read)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'load'
```

Comment: I think you meant `users = json.load(read)`? Not sure what the line after that is supposed to do, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're couple of typos in your code, and I corrected accordingly

```
import json
users=[]
with open('username project.json','w') as f:
    jfile=json.dump(users,f)

def create_usernames():
    username=input('Enter in username')
    with open('username project.json','r+') as read:
        usersj=json.load(read) # <-- updated this
    if username in usersj: # <-- and this
            print('username rejected')
    else:
        print('username is okay')
create_usernames()
```

Tested both the scenarios where a username exists and does not exist

Comment: @
KulasangarI dont have enough reputation to

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
users=[]
with open('username project.json','w') as f:
    jfile=json.dump(users,f)

def create_usernames():
    username=input('Enter in username')
    with open('username project.json','r+') as users: #changed this to users
       usersj=users.load(read)
    if username in users[usersj]:
            print('username rejected')
    else:
        print('username is okay')
create_usernames()
```

are you trying to load the json users? because list doesn't have any load method